# How to sandbox an included framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, app-store, sandbox

After a number of successful submissions of my sandboxed app to the App Store, today Apple decided to reject my app because a 3rd party framework it includes and links against is not sandboxed. I don't recall hearing about sandboxing frameworks separately. I know they need to be codesigned, and this one is.

Searching through the docs and online doesn't turn up any info about framework sandboxing.

Can anyone point me to documentation or a tutorial on how to sandbox my third party framework. (I do have access to its source code, if necessary, but I did not see any obvious option to sandbox the framework when I opened and examined the framework's project in Xcode.

Comment: Did you find out the solution to this?

Comment: Never mind: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/320851-how-to-sandbox-an-included-framework.html